# Reference request for an introduction to deformation theory in algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, rt.representation-theory, deformation-theory

I'd like some introductory references for deformation theory in algebraic geometry. I'm interested in survey articles too but I primarily want references which give all the definitions and go through the basics carefully and also give some idea of the link between deformation theory and intersection theory and/or K-theory. Texts with examples would be particularly nice. Applications to representation theory would also be useful to me.

As a specific example, I would like to understand how deformation theory helps in understanding the geometry of the Hilbert scheme of points on a surface (and the geometry of more general moduli spaces like Nakajima quiver varieties, if possible).

My background in geometry is Hartshorne and some material on constructible sheaves and D-modules. I've also come across some deformation theory from the representation theory side.

Thank you for the help.

Edit: I'm also perfectly happy with references that only deal with complex algebraic geometry.

Comment: Hartshorne has a book on Deformation Theory too. Have you looked at Greuel, Lossen, Shustin - Introduction to Singularities and Deformations (2007) ?

Comment: I just took a look at it. It's not exactly what I'm looking for but it has some interesting stuff. The appendix looks useful. Thanks.

Comment: try Palamodov:http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=3728&option_lang=eng or some of the other references here:  http://www.icmat.es/congresos/STM/abstracts/vanStraten.pdf  and everyone bases their treatment on the 1964 Harvard PhD thesis of M. Schlessinger

Comment: Perhaps you may try Eisenbud and Harris forthcoming book: http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic720403.files/book.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try Sernesi's book (deformations of algebraic schemes).